# Entity Framework 6 - GetObjectStateEntries expected modified entities have state "Unchanged"

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, model

**Issue**

When I create my Account-class as example A, the object appears with state "EntityState.Modified" in my SaveChanges()-method as expected.

When I use example B, the object appears as "EntityState.Unchanged" and does no apear in the result of the GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified) call.

Can anyone explain to me, why the model object appears unchanged in example B while everything works in example A?

Thankyou

**Classes**

I update 'Created' and 'LastUpdated' using this method in my Context object:

```
public class CrmContext : DbContext
{

public override int SaveChanges()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified))
    {
        if (!entry.IsRelationship)
        {
            var account = entry.Entity as Account;
            if (account != null)
            {
                account.LastUpdated = now;
                if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
                {
                    account.Created = now;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}

}
```

Model example A (WORKING):

```
public class Account
{
 [Key]
 public int AccountId { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 [Timestamp]
 public Byte[] TimeStamp { get; set; }
 public DateTime Created { get; set; }
 public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

Model example B (NOT WORKING):

```
public class Account : BaseObject
{
 [Key]
 public int AccountId { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class BaseObject
{
 [Timestamp]
 public Byte[] TimeStamp { get; set; }
 public DateTime Created { get; set; }
 public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The problem does not seem to have anything to do with whether the model class inherits from a base class or not as I cannot reproduce a working example without using the suggested DetectChanges() call.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should call change detection manually at the beginning of the overridden `SaveChanges` method:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    this.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

    //...
}
```

I have no explanation why the entity state might be different for model A and model B. But the missing call to `DetectChanges` generally can be a reason why an entity is in state `Unchanged` (temporarily) although it has been modified. For example if you have POCO entities (not change tracking proxies), just load an entity, change a property and then call your overridden `SaveChanges` the state will be `Unchanged` *until* `base.SaveChanges` is called which would update the state to `Modified` and save the change to the database. But your code that sets the `LastUpdated` property would have been skipped and `LastUpdated` had the old value in the database.

Comment: That fixed it. Thankyou SO much for taking your time to write this. :)

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks so much.